# Creating a "halo" effect for a material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to this image:
[image: Sparks]

However it's looking more like this:
[image: Lame]

No halo; the material ends where the mesh ends.

How can I set a material to look like the first image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21739/how-to-render-lightning-in-cycles/28371. I think using compositing nodes in this case along with **Emission** node in object's material is a way to go.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender and:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/post-processing-lightsabers-in-blender and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing

Comment: That's usually done in the compositor with glare or blur node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of effect is usually created in post processing.  In Blender's compositor I found that the *Filter* > *Blur* node gives a result quite close to what you are looking for, though the *Glare* node may also work.

Just go the the *Node Editor* view, switch to compositing nodes, and drop a Blur node in between the *Render Layers* and *Composite* nodes.  I found that using *Fast Gaussian* seems to produce the best looking effect.

[image]

---

To get that even wider glow you can add a second blur node with a much larger blur and mix it with the smaller blur.  Set the mix mode to *Add* and adjust the *Fac* slider to suit your tastes.

[image]
*Click to enlarge.*

---

For the actual mesh I just used the IvyGen technique [outlined here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1886/5705) with a very strong volumetric emission shader (and no surface shader).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can accomplish this in cycles.
But you have to add a little bit more geometry.

The easiest way for me to imagine you starting to experiment with this method is:

1. Try adding a cube that encompasses your lightning tree.
2. Shrinkwrap the cube to your tree, make sure to add an offset.
3. Add a new material to your shrunkwrapped cube.
4. Add an **Emission** node.
5. Plug it into the volume of the material output.
6. Set emission color to a darker royal blue.
7. Set emission strength to 1.0

APPENDING RESULTS OF COMMENTS BELOW:
[image]

1. Create the Tree with extruded Verts.
2. Add Skin Modifier.
3. Duplicate this object (Original Object = RED, Duplicated Object = YELLOW).
4. On the YELLOW object, apply the skin modifier.
5. Then add the Solidify Modifier, and set offset to one.
6. Add a Subsurf Modifier to the RED object.
7. Apply the material setup as shown to each of the objects.

The results are obviously a starting point to tweak for the look you want. However this is a pretty decent one, considering it needs no post-processing in the compositor, unless you really need to pull off the blurred effect.

@MrZak Thanks for the input.

Comment: It isn't necessary to add cube and shrinkwrap it to lightning (and that may be quite complex task to fit that mesh properly as lightning may be quite curved); just enough to add **Skin** modifier to lightning mesh.

Comment: You are very correct, there are better ways, solidify works really well too, and you can control the offset value pretty accurately to.