# How do you create an electric aura in blender?

Tags: effects

Im trying to figure out how to create an electric aura of a simple shape (cube). Would anyone know how i could easily do this?

Here is an example of what i'm talking about:

[image]

With sonic you can see electricity around him. I'm trying to figure out how i can do the same with a simple cube.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "electric aura"?

Comment: Please be more specific, maybe post an image of what you're trying to achieve and what you have achieved yet.

Comment: I've posted the sample image above. Hope im being abit more specific.

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46660/creating-a-halo-effect-for-a-material-in-cycles

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21739