# Changing Color of alpha Principled Shader - Node Setup

Tags: materials, node-editor

Could someone please show me the correct node setup so the Orange color logo and lines sit on top of the dark blue. I've done my best with the node setup but the orange colour is very dull. I'd like to be able to change orange color separately to the blue.[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the alpha channel as to control the mix of color that is used on the surface. The basic principle is explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: Or read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110413/change-color-associated-with-transparency/110502#110502