# Texture transparency problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I wanted to cover my model with fur, but I can't make my hair band look transparent [image]

Here's my nodes. I've watched a bunch of videos and tutorials but still can't figure this out. What am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: I meant to write "Hi, everyone.", but the first part of it wiped away somehow

Comment: Can you try inverting the inputs of the Diffuse and Transparency shaders into the Mix shader?

Comment: It turned pink in material view and in render view it's now semitransparent

Comment: Does the image texture have an alpha channel then?

Comment: Uhh, maybe?.. I don't know, I'm still new to 3D and most of the time I don't know what I'm doing

Comment: Hey, I think it's now working! Didn't even register what happened, I just randomly was turning shaders on and off

Comment: Might be that you needed to force Blender to reload the image texture so it would draw.

Comment: Yeah! The texture for a moment went purple, I reloaded it and it now it workes! Thank you, kind stranger!

Comment: How do I update this post so it's now answered?

Comment: Make an answer post below with a screen capture of the fixed setup, and then you will be able to mark it as the solution tomorrow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes/27635#27635

Answer (score 2):

All is working now, thanks to  Craig D Jones [image]
[image]

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110413/change-color-associated-with-transparency/110502#110502 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material