# Transparent material is black

Tags: materials, transparency

So I've got this eye texture that is supposed to be transparent, and it was when I was working on a different project, but I decided to restart.

[image: Eye text]

So I reloaded everything like the models materials and armature, but the eye texture remained black. I can't figure out how to fix it.
[image: waluigi2]
[image: waluigi1]
[image: waluigi3]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110413/change-color-associated-with-transparency/110502#110502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cycles diffuse node does not support transparency on its own. In the material nodes you need to add a transparency node and mix it with the textures alpha channel with a mix node. If you had it transparent from the start it might've been using the blender internal rendering engine which you can change from the top bar where it says cycles render and switching it to blender render.

If you plan on atlasing the textures, using cycles does not support transparency when baking textures.

[image: Setting up the diffusenode to support transparency]

Answer (score 3):

I was also seeing black and I redid my nodes but it still didn't work. I finally figured out my issue. I had set max transparency bounces to 0. D'oh. Go to LIGHT PATHS > MAX BOUNCES and ensure you have at least 2 for Transparency.