# UV Mapping Transparent Images onto a Model, Blender 2.8Beta!

Tags: transparency

So I am currently trying to figure our how I can take my Logo, and put it across a cube on one face. I want the Cube to be gold. and my label lay across it while allowing the gold to appear through.

I seem to have gotten it to work on the Cycles engine. But On the Eevee engine, the transparent area is black. Is there a way around this? or is it true, that in the current version of blender, getting this transparency just isn't stable yet?

This First image is me attempting to use the "Alpha Blend" but it just makes the entire face transparent. 
[image: Alpha Blend]
Then in this picture  I turned the Alpha Blend off, and it made the transparent section black.( all of these "Alpha" options end up eliminating the entire faces opaqueness)
[image: No Alpha Blend]
Then here is another weird thing happening. When i put this into the Cycles engine, the Top part looks great, exactly how i want it. BUT the other sides seem to be reflecting light a lot less. Almost as if the transparent part of the Label's PNG is adding a layer of gloss to the surface.[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no need to use a transparent shader. Read the following links: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447) and [change color associated with transparency](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110413/change-color-associated-with-transparency/110502#110502)

Comment: I figured it out. I had to use a principled shader instead of the transparent shader in order to bring out the gold underneath. still not sure exactly how the theory works, but it worked!

Comment: Read the links. The principle is simple: you use the alpha channel of the image to control a mix. You can mix the color of the shader or you can mix two shaders. The alpha channel determines how the mix is done.