# Transparent image shows black in viewport

Tags: rendering, node-editor, transparency

Im not the best at blender but I've been hacking away at this issue to no avail. I have a transparent image as a texture in blender but in rendering it shows with a black background... I've researched the issue a lot and I will link the methods I've tried down below as well. I'll [attach a video of my blender](https://youtu.be/zh5Nwe5M7LA) too so you can see what the issue is.

Additional info: All of this was imported through pc2 export from CLO3d, I'm on a Mac and im using Eevee

Already tried all of these node setups:

https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-alpha-transparent-textures-in-blender/

[Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

[Texture with transparency becomes black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209782/texture-with-transparency-becomes-black)

EDIT: Added the pngs I used
[image: Image that was compiled in PC2]
[image: Seperate image I used]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (remove all the useless parts and pack the images)?

Comment: There is something strange in your video - the _Image Texture_ node has the _Alpha_ settings greyed out as if they were not available... usually even on an image without alpha transparency you can change those settings... so maybe uploading your file would be a good idea. By the way, the "How to set up a material for transparency in Blender" section of that artisticrender site is nonsense. With the _Principled BSDF_ node it is not necessary to mix it with a _Transparent BSDF_ node by the alpha channel as factor, but I noticed you did not do that in your video anyway.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I have tried using the image compiled in the pc2 zip from clo3d as well as a separate file with the exact same image as png and it comes with the same results. I'll add both of the files in an edit.

Comment: Well, this site is focusing on tools and addons shipped with Blender, I have no idea what this pc2 export from CLO3D does. At least I know now why the alpha option is deactivated in the texture node: you have modified the image (intentionally or accidentally?) in _Texture Paint_ mode and not saved the changes. The other thing is, I don't know which render engine you are using, but the _Material Preview_ (which is visible in the video) always uses _Eevee_. Therefore you have to change the _Blend Mode_ in the material settings to something else than _Opaque_ to get alpha transparency.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann YOU GOT IT THNAK U SO MUCH I HAD TO CHANGE THE BLEND MODD TO SOMETHING OTHER THAN OPAQUE

Comment: The second answer in the link [Texture with transparency becomes black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209782/texture-with-transparency-becomes-black) which you had posted yourself in the question would have given you that solution already.