# light-Saber / Dr Strange VFX

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, animation-nodes, fire

fellas! Does anybody know how to recreate in Blender Light-Saber effect, similarly to popular plugin for after effects Saber by video-copilot, but in 3D? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reSXGxkyr0k)
Eventually I wanna achieve effect similar to the one from drStrange (see pics)

Any Ideas would be helpful , thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on youtube about how to do an electric arc. I haven't done any of those though so I won't be able to explain here

Comment: Of potential interest: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21739/3127, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3636/3127, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1096/3127

Answer (score -1):

Using Emission node from the cycles render may help you.
This video might help you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJyZJRJdU8I