# How can I make a ramification with curves?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm using curves to make a ramification because I need to model 3D veins for another bigger model, the interior of the human body. Is there any way to make a ramification with (Bézier) curves, or should this be done in a different way?

Comment: somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/how-to-create-an-animated-electric-arc-or-lightning

Comment: You may want to watch the [topiary tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/creating-topiary/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Sapling tree generator, which is built in newest Blender version (user preferences -> addons -> search "sapling" -> enable (tick the box) -> in 3D view Shift+A -> curve :)
Play with the settings, and I'm sure, you'll find what you want ;)