# How to create the effect of a flaming/electric cyllinder

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm wanting to make another lightsaber movie.  The first one I made, [The Battle of Harris Beach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__phdvGKam8) simply used an animated cylinder that was motion blurred, colored, and then overlayed on top of the footage as seen in this picture:
[image: Normal Method]

This works great, but unfortunately, the new trailer has somewhat raised the bar,  [as seen at 1:57 in the new trailer.](https://youtu.be/sGbxmsDFVnE?t=1m57s)  They not only glow, but appear to be flaming and have some sort of lightning travelling through them.  What would be the best way of accomplishing this effect?  Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1875/599

Comment: Yeah, that looks related. Do you know of a good way to constrain the lightening to a pre animated cylinder in that case?

Comment: @gandalf3 Is there a function that constrains the ends of one object to those of another?

Comment: IIRC that addon has an option for constraining the lightning inside a container object. You could try generating all the lightning bolts inside a reference cylinder, then parenting a particle emitter to the animated cylinder.

Comment: @gandalf3 Okay, I tried to figure out how the addon works.  I installed it and opened the example file from the website, but it crashes every time I click on the Misc tab in the tool bar to get to the settings.

Comment: Works for me.. Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: @gandalf3 It said: "Writing: /tmp/FSLG_EXAMPLEv027.crash.txt"

Comment: @gandalf3 Okay, I got it to work by importing objects from the example blend.  Looks like this could be promising.  How do I set up a material for the lightning?

Comment: @gandalf3 Oh, it has to be wireframe.  Okay, I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: @gandalf3 Okay, I'm getting some decent results!  Thanks for the ideas.  I probably will just use it for when the lightsabers turn on or something.  The lightning generator is a little too choppy compared to things like After Effect's automatic lightning maker.  But, I very well might use it for some force lightning effects!

Comment: btw, I just saw this posted on Blendernation, http://www.blendernation.com/2015/11/27/tutorial-blender-2-76-comprehensive-lightsabers-in-opengl/

Comment: @m.ardito  Cool! I'll look into it.