# More realistic lightning motion in Blender

Tags: effects

I used the solution to create animated lightning found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/how-to-create-an-animated-electric-arc-or-lightning) to do the Sith lightning effects for my film (the effect can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/dpENrCozv34?t=1m16s)). Cool, but not cool enough.  Each particle is completely random compared to previous particles, and does not behave like the cool lightning found in After Effects for example: [this](https://youtu.be/BgAlQuqzl8o?t=1m21s) or [this](https://youtu.be/xjVc3M-ofIw?t=1m41s) or [this](https://youtu.be/3X648cuc61E?t=1m26s). How can I animate a mesh or other object to *behave* and move more naturally like lightning?

Gracias.

Comment: Maybe not exactly related, but you could try to scale lightning mesh way down in Object mode without applying rotation and in Skin modifier change settings for *Mean Radius*. This would allow to have lightning with small branches, like in [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0WGD48MXNc).

Comment: @MrZak That looks good, but remember that I want each bolt to have its own motion and not be static.