# How to make branch from bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I have just a normal bezier curve. And i have sub divide once. I want to extrude the sub divide vertex. Like the branch. But when i extrude the handle is remove and when i extruded from the handle it is extruded good way. I just want to make the branch type.
[image]

[image]

Comment: bezier curves cannot be split in branches or forked in multiple directions.

Comment: see also this related post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/how-to-create-an-animated-electric-arc-or-lightning

Comment: I don't know what  you are trying to achieve but maybe you can use the the sapling add on

Comment: @cegaton im trying to extrude the curve as we do to mesh if we subdivide the edge and extrude and we get branch or edge same way i need in the curve. Im making the spiderman on its face its has web so i took the curve and want to subdivde and make branch and make a web on the face

Comment: Again, you can't split a branch out of a curve.