# Might it be possible to use scripts in blender to do what Mandelbulber does?

Tags: python, modifiers

This would be a sort of extension of this question: [Fractals in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/fractals-in-blender).

I was playing around in unity and found a tutorial for making fractal objects via C# scripts. I used the script from the tutorial and set up a scene to port to android and discovered the frame rate when looking at the fractal object was extremely low due to the vert count and number of individual objects. As I was unable to figure out how to merge the meshes properly in unity I figured I'd turn to blender with python scripts since I figured I could do the same thing in python and have seen how simple it is to copy and merge meshes via the array modifier.

Long story short, after trying to find scripting tutorials for blender 2.7 and getting lost in the API I started to wonder if what I'm trying to do is even possible. What is my end goal, you ask? I want to make a fractal landscape similar to what you might generate in mandelbulber, but finite in each direction. Fake 'infinite depth' is also unnecessary, as I'm fine with simply stopping recursion at a predefined depth. I want this landscape to be a single mesh that I can export to unity.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can generate such fractals at finite poly resolution.

You just need to figure out the fractal math and positions of vertices. Then you can build such mesh in python with the [BMesh module](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.html).