# creating fractal materials with node editor

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, mathematics

does anybody know how to generate a 2D fractal like the classic Mandelbrot set, as a 2D material using the node editor? im looking to make something similar to how the texture nodes like the wave texture node operates to create zoomable and editable fractals. i am familiar with using math nodes but i have no idea how to start with this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/fractals-in-blender

Comment: There's a fractal add on on Blender Market. Check it out: https://www.blendermarket.com/products/fractal-explorer