# How to create a Sierpinski Dodecahedron fractal

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, mathematics, geometry-nodes

I can create a Menger sponge fractal using geometry nodes.

[image: Image1:]

[image: im1a]

[image: im2a]

See Blender file below:
[image]

Now I'm trying to create a Sierpinski Dodecahedron

[image: Image2]

I tried to replace the cube node with a Dodecahedron created as an object but that didn't work

[image: Image3]

The goal is to create the Sierpinski Dodecahedron fractal that can be sliced into several sections and 3D printed out.

Comment: Have been discussing this with @lemon just recently .. have got [this far](https://imgur.com/a/Oyz7Jt6).. but running into floating-point errors in the dodecahedral case. Got to get the maths right for the scaling factor. And I know, on my machine, if I go one level further I will crash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

one more instance level:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great stuff! How did you determine your scale factor? I wound up with accumulating deviations..  (Mind you, the resolution will surely be greater than any printer's, anyway...)

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I just read the wiki article 

Comment: One more level and my computer still worked but Blender crashed everytime…

Comment: :) I thought I'd read the right wiki article.. but apparently not... link?   I think we still both have  a problem... coincident (duplicate) instances ?? .. you could maybe squeeze another level out..

Comment: i read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-flake

Comment: that gives the scale factor for instances _in_ the corners: `1/(2+phi)` I've still got to work out the factor for instances _on_ the corners? I'll get to it.. my neurons aren't firing  atm. Need coffee.

Comment: Thanks! I really think doing fractals is geometry nodes will make life easier.  I've looked into Animation Nodes and L-Systems but geometry nodes opens another door...It also helps that the creator of Animation Nodes is also working on Geometry Nodes and adding loops to it :-)

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3):

[image: test]

[image: test2]

This setup works for every fractal.
The current scale factor (the Value and its Math node) is set to scale dodecahedrons, but it can be adjusted for other primitives (usually you would change the Power to a Multiply).

To anyone who wants to render this, I recommend 3.0.1, because more recent versions cause artifacts with overlapping geometry (it's a known regression).