# How best to store a single Boolean value for later reference

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to store a boolean value with a Named Attribute node to use in a switch later in another node group.  Is there a better way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's "normal" because switch geometry switches geometry (it's a circle in the output) and geometry can only be switched once per frame (as a whole) while you are saving the boolean value to a point (which is a field value -> output as diamond). Maybe you should tell us a bit more what you want to achieve? since you didn't show/tell us what you want to achieve, you can replace your tree with this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rCNG.png it is the same functionality

Comment: and i am sure now you will say "but i want..." that's why you should always(!) give details what you want to achieve instead of just ask "technical" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is correct, but the value will be duplicated for each element in the chosen domain the attribute uses. In case of heavy geometries this could be unnecessarily wasteful, so you may store this attribute in a separate geometry.

For example, when creating a [Koch Snowflake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/287078/60486), since I don't use a point cloud in my setup, I create a separate point, and separate components or join geometries to get/set just that single point's attribute:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Markus.  That’s really helpful