# 2d mandelbrot set generation with script

Tags: modeling, scripting

I would like to find a script to create a 2d Mandelbrot set in the 3d workspace. is there any way to do this or is it impossible? Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/fractals-in-blender

Comment: maybe a little bit late, but I have just done what I think you want.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnPxRci2HY0 Regards
Javier