# Mirror an object via modifiers on a point(instead of a plane)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I would like to use modifiers to mirror and rotate an object.
Or simply, mirror on a point, not a plane.

Left on the image is the simple mirror modifier using the x-axis.
I want to have the situation on the right, where the object is mirrored and
rotated.

Red points correspond to each other.
It would be easier than copying and rotating the object, because I
want to model some kind of matching, point-wise symmetric chain links.

[image: Red dots correspond to the same point, but mirrored. Left: Mirror modifier for x-axis. Right: Mirrored point-wise]

Comment: further examples of [how to use the mirror modifier](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/566/when-is-it-useful-to-mirror)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create an empty at the origin of your object.
2. Rotate it 180° relative to the object's rotation.
3. Add an *Array* modifier to your object, and disable all offsets.
4. Enable *Object Offset* and select the empty from the list.

[image: Example setup]

Using the *Object Offset* can be a very powerful tool

[image]

Another Solution to this would be to use a linked copy, created with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and rotate that 180°. Linked copies share the same mesh.