# Is there a way to create half of a model and duplicate other side

Tags: modeling, mesh

So far I have been modeling by making both sides of a model but I got annoyed due to having to make the exact changes on both sides. Is there a way to make only one side of the model and automatically get the same output for the other side?

Comment: You need to use the mirror modifier. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/566/when-is-it-useful-to-mirror

Comment: IMO not a duplicate, this question is asking if it's possible, not when it's useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes there definitely is.**

You can use the [`Mirror Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html),  this will mirror your model across its origin (or any other object's origin) and merge the vertices along the seam if you want as well.

To do this first add the Mirror Modifier to the object in the [`Modifiers`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html) panel.

[image]

The entire mesh will be mirrored across the object's origin along the selected axis.

[image]

[image]

You can tell it to merge the vertices along the seam by checking *merge* and adjusting the *merge limit* to set how close together vertices must be to be merged.

If you don't want to mirror across the origin you can use any other object's origin as the mirror point.  I usually use an [`Empty`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/empties.html), which is just a non-renderable object that is used in situations like this.

To do this first add an *Empty* under <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty* > *Plain Axes*.

[image]

Then select the Empty in the *Mirror Object* dropdown of the Mirror Modifier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful if you could add some images/steps as to how someone could do this.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot I am working on them right now :).

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do it is mirroring. But there is an allternate method :).

Select the whole mesh and check the 'X Mirror' and 'Topology Mirror' in the *'Tool Options'*

[image]

Now when you edit one side of the mesh the other one behave the same.
[image]