# issue with mirrior modifier

Tags: modifiers, mirror

Look at this screenshot why this will happen i absolute beginner in blender and use this blueprints [link](http://www.cartype.com/pics/9793/full/chevrolet_camaro_2010.jpg) i want mirror other side of object not down   [image]

Comment: You have to place the origin point in a right position to mirror the object correctly. See this links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18934/is-their-a-way-to-create-half-of-a-model-and-duplicate-other-side , http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to go into the object mode and apply the rotation. Go into the object mode, select your object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and then apply rotation.

Comment: What key is Strg?

Comment: Control...We here in austria have the "shortcut" for control strg.. which one do you have?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that would be the Ctrl key.

Comment: But when i want to move car and mirror will also move and will go seprate i want to move together

Comment: @Raminlich What's the problem? Don't understand it from the comment you gave. Maybe you can sent a screenshot or explain it better, Thanks

Comment: @Raminlich If you move an object in edit mode, the origin will not move, and since the mirror modifier mirrors around the origin, the mirror will change. In object mode it should work properly.